# Problems viewing KML used in V2 in Gmap V3

Tags: kml, sidebar

I'm having problems displaying my KML in Gmap V3; It works fine in my V2 code, but haven't been able to display it in V3.

I tested it on the google maps page, but all I see are the folder names; the folders won't open and the sites do not appear.
I can also open the KML in GE, but the sites don't appear on the map, only in the sidebar, and the links in the info windows aren't working.

I can view a smaller prototype of [my kml](http://landval.gsfc.nasa.gov/doc4T.kml) using some [test code](http://timhaverland.s3.amazonaws.com/work/finss/kmllayersimpletest02.html) I found , but I can't view my [full version kml](http://landval.gsfc.nasa.gov/doc6T.kml)  with this same test code. 
And haven't been able to get either KML to display in any of my own v3 code yet.

The full KML contains 4 folders and hundreds of sites, but even the smaller prototype, which contains less than 100 points will not display in my own V3 code, yet as stated earlier, it works fine in my v2 map (which is really still a prototype), view-able [here](http://landval.gsfc.nasa.gov/Test/GM_sidebar2.html%20here)

(I didn't want to go much further with this v2, only to have to migrate to v3 in a matter of months.)

What I'd like to implement is something like the [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_icon_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/visualisationmagazine_com_lacreativemap_kml.xml).

(Should this exmaple be able to display any KML that is publicly available by changing the filename in the URL?)

It's the closest thing I've seen so far to what I'd like to have:

I need a sidebar to display a lot of points, which a user can turn on and off.
I also need folders.
Finally, I want a full global view - and as such, cannot use GE.

Please can you offer any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geoxml3 is subject to the same domain xmlhttp security policy.  It can only display kml files from other domains by using a proxy.

It looks like you are using the GeoXml third party parser.  There is a v3 version of that at:

http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/

Your second file is not technically valid:

```
<Placemark>
        <name>Dillon</name>
        <description><![CDATA[Click on the site name to proceed to the ftp 
                    directory for the <a href="ftp://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/subsets/cn_Dillon_18_WSW_MT/">Dillon</a> CRN site.]]></description>
        <styleUrl>#CRN</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-113.0057,45.158,0</coordinates>
        </Point>                    
            <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
</Placemark>
```

from the 4T file has `<Point>...</Point>`, which is different from the 6T file which has `<point>...</point>`:

```
<Placemark>
  <name>Dillon</name>
  <description><![CDATA[Click on the site name link below to proceed to the subset ftp directory for the <a href="ftp://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/subsets/cn_Dillon_18_WSW_MT">Dillon</a> CRN site.]]>    </description>
  <styleUrl>#CRN</styleUrl>
  <point><coordinates>-113.0057,45.158,0</coordinates></point>
 </Placemark>
```

Comment: doesn't really explain why it can display one and not the other, the kml files are in the same place so any security issues would affect them equally

Comment: also, I was using GeoXml in the V2 version, the simpletest code that I was trying to implement uses google.maps.KmlLayer and google.maps.Map

Comment: wow.   I'm afraid I'd never have seen that!   I guess it works with Gmap2 but not v3?   I'll reconstruct and try again. Thanks!